# if plugin is active? check if plugin is enabled or not?

Tags: plugins, php, functions

I'm using the mingle plugin and the mingle-forum plugin.

I want to show a certain part on my site only if those two plugins are active. How can I solve this?

```
<?php if ( is_plugin_active('mingle-forum') ) { ?>
                    <div id="login"><?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/inc/userlogin.php' ); ?></div>
                <?php } ?>
```

This throws a php error. Call to undefined function is_plugin_active

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

update:

```
<?php if ( plugin_active('plugin-directory/mingle-forum/wpf-main.php') ) { ?>
                    <div id="login"><?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/inc/userlogin.php' ); ?></div>
                <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Where (what file or hook) do you use this function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This function exists in `wp-admin/includes/plugin.php` so I'm assuming it doesn't get included by the theme.

You can either `require` it, or just create your own version of it - see here: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/is_plugin_active

UPDATED:

Please check [`is_plugin_active`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_plugin_active/)

Comment: thank you, i might have found a solution but I still can't get it working. The function plugin_active is set in my functions.php file and doesn't through an error. However my div.login does NEVER show up, doesn't matter if the plugin is active or not. Maybe I'm checking for the wrong path? Any idea what I could do wrong here?

Comment: found the solution. "plugin-directory" of course has to be the name of the directory where the actual plugin file is in. I thought "plugin-directory" is the path to the dir where all the plugin files are in.

Comment: exactly mathiregster, that's what everyone seems to be missing here. `plugin-directory` is most likely going to be the name of your plugin

Answer (score 5):

There are two way by which you can check plugin is active or not.

1. You can use **is_plugin_active** function to check plugin active or
   not.
2. If plugin have class then you can check like below-

   ```
   if (class_exists('YITH_Woocompare_Frontend')) 
   {
   echo 'your code';
   }
   ```

The above class related to **YITH WooCommerce Compare** plugin . The above code check if class exist then only you code inside the bracket will execute.

Comment: was about to upvote, but the class thing is just totally false. What happens if the class name is changed? and is_plugin_active is basically the accepted answer :(

Answer (score 3):

You can also try to check plugin is Active or Not

```
$pluginList = get_option( 'active_plugins' );
$plugin = 'PLUGIN_DIR/FILE_NAME.php'; 
if ( in_array( $plugin , $pluginList ) ) {
    // Plugin 'mg-post-contributors' is Active
}
```

Also try below code for simplicity

```
if ( is_plugin_active( 'PLUGIN_DIR/FILE_NAME.php' ) ) {
  //plugin is activated
}
```

Comment: The poster was unable to use `is_plugin_active` because it is only available from admin pages.

Comment: This solution helped me verify the plugin name. Tks

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the WordPress default function. This function exists in `wp-admin/includes/plugin.php`.

Simply pass the Path to the plugin file relative to the plugins directory.

```php
$pluginPath = 'akismet/akismet.php';
if ( is_plugin_active( $pluginPath ) ) {
    echo 'Plugin is activated';
} else {
   echo 'Plugin is not activated';
}
```

For more details on `is_plugin_active` please see the below link:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_plugin_active/

Comment: Thank you, @Sohel Khan; that hint was really useful to me; I use/d it to start building a health bar for my site :) Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

the correct and actual way to check if a plugin is active or not is to set a

> function_exists ()

function for your code

Comment: Welcome to wpse! *the correct and actual way to check if a plugin is active or not is to set function_exists*. What if a plugin is OO and doesn't use any functions, only methods, your answer fails to address this situation.